# Channeling IPv4 packets to IPv6 packets between interfaces

Tags: ipv6, forwarding, ipv4

How do I route packets in my machine between interfaces (See yellow arrow). Eth0 receives IPv4 packets and I will like to channel it to Eth1 which will send IPv6 packets out.[Image of dual stack machine with IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkQxg.png)

Comment: Have a look there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64 , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Stateless_IP/ICMP_Translation  . A linux implementation: https://www.jool.mx/en/intro-xlat.html

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? IPv4 over a IPv6 network? If so a GRE tunnell may be a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Routing cannot convert between IPv4 and IPv6. You need an application layer gateway for that.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols, and cannot be directly routed between.

Move everything to IPv6 and you can have a single stack all the way through, which can be directly routed.

Or, tunnel IPv4 in IPv6. Maybe GRE, or some other VPN.

Or, insert a middlebox in between, terminating the IPv4 connection and starting an IPv6 one. Some kind of proxy or load balancer, for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!

Comment: May I check for tunneling IPv4 in IPv6, what should I google for to find out how it works. Does it mean that whenever I reach the IPv6 leg, I should package the IPv4 packets within IPv6, transport it over the IPv6 protocol and then remove it and revert back to IPv4 when required?

Comment: Design whatever network you need such that A can talk to C. If it must be IPv4, could have a 4 in 6 tunnel from B to C, and a new IPv4 address for C.  Or, IPv6 only throughout could simplify things.